# How do I install crm module in odoo9

Tags: odoo-9

I am unable to install the crm module in odoo9. when trying to install crm module in odoo9 then getting below error. please give the reference..

You try to install module 'crm' that depends on module 'resource'.
But the latter module is not available in your system.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have files of this module:
go to apps menu and remove the default filter apps in search view and search for resource module if you don't have it you need to upload it.
Check in your installation folder in the /addons directory if this file exists.

1. if is not you must download it. if the folder exists then you need
   to update the list of application active the developer mode and you
   will have new menus under the menu apps try to update the list then
   search for this module by name and install it
2. else you need to download the file and put it in your addons directory and update the apps list.

> note if you don't know how to active developer mode and update the list youtube should have videos will gide you simply

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the following two-step

**Step 1**

> First, you check the 'resource' in odoo App, I have included the
>   screenshot also for the more help. if found install it. it will solve
>   your problem.   [step-1-Search-in-odoo-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3HVM.png)

If you didn't get the app in odoo app. Follow this second step 2.

**Step 2**

> Download the 'resource' module from this link. Install it and upgrade.
>   https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/9.0/resource/